# My texture is deformed!

Tags: texturing

[image]

[image]

When I apply a texture to my surface this is what happens.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

It may be because your UV map is deformed. Check in the UV editor and if your map seems deformed: in the viewport select the top of your counter in edit mode, go in top view by pressing 7 then press U and click Project from view. (Scale your UV map afterwards to get a decent result)

It should work after that ;)